# The SDK directory does not exist (ubuntu 16.04) (react native)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, react-native

I am trying to run react native project on Ubuntu 16.04 .

The $PATH is correct according to the documentation.

when I `echo $PATH`  , following is shown :

> /home/yash/bin:/home/yash/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/yash/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/yash/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/root/Android/Sdk/tools:/root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

The error is shown when running `react-native run-android` :

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/root/Android/Sdk' does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you exported ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: @ArnoldGandarillasCastillo yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/root` directory has special permissions that probably prevent react-native from accessing it. You should put the Android SDK in a directory that is readable by your user (e.g. , `/home/yash/android`).

Comment: how do I copy it if access is denied ? :(

Comment: You can use `sudo` to copy the folder.